# How to select from the same table 2 diffrent condition in the same select (Oracle stored procedure)

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I have a table with 4 coulmens and a stored procedure thet select from that table.
DOC_ID; CUSTOMER_TYPE_ID ;CATEGORY_ID; REQUIERD_STATUS;
Until now  the select was preaty simple, by passing the params of customerId and the categoryCode we got the docId and the requierdStatus

Now i want to add another column "Activity_ID"(nullable) that set a an activity code so we could be more specific.
FOR EXAMPLE : until now
custTypeId = 1 and CategoryCode =2
got me 2 rows 
custTypeId = 1, DocId = 1 ,requierdStatus =3 , CategoryCode = 2
custTypeId = 1, DocId = 2 ,requierdStatus =3 , CategoryCode = 2

By adding the activityCode coulmn we want to controll the requierd status like this
DocId = 1 ,requierdStatus =3 , CategoryCode = 2, ActivityId = null
DocId = 1 ,requierdStatus =4 , CategoryCode = 2, ActivityId = 10

Basicly if document doesnt have a specific activityCode then its should be selcted by the category.

In my select i need to be able to select the by the ActivityId  but if there no row answerd to that condition then i want to get the row by category.
What cant happen is that i will get both rows, one row by activity and another by the category.

I should only get one row or zero.

How can i do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're doing, you seem to want:

```
select min(t.doc_id) keep (dense_rank first order by t.activity_id),
  min(t.required_status) keep (dense_rank first order by t.activity_id)
into ... -- unless opening a ref cursor
from your_table t
where t.customer_type_id = p_customer_type_id
and (t.activity_id = p_activity_id
 or (t.activity_id is null and t.category_id = p_category_id))
group by t.customer_type_id, t.category_id;
```

where `p_customer_type_id`, `p_category_id` and `p_activity_id` are the parameters for your procedure. That's assuming that you only want to fall back to searching by category is the table activity ID is null, which I think is what you're describing. And that the value passed into the procedure won't also be null; if it can be then that just complicates it a bit more.

[Read more about the `keep dense_rank first` construct.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions056.htm) Basically it's determining which single row within the grouped data is kept in the result set.

Quick demo using your sample data (if I've interpreted right...):

```
create table your_table (doc_id number, customer_type_id number,
  category_id number, required_status number, activity_id number);

insert into your_table (doc_id, customer_type_id,
  category_id, required_status, activity_id)
values (1, 1, 2, 3, null);

insert into your_table (doc_id, customer_type_id,
  category_id, required_status, activity_id)
values (1, 1, 2, 4, 10);
```

As a procedure with an OUT ref cursor argument:

```
create or replace procedure your_proc (p_customer_type_id number,
  p_category_id number, p_activity_id number, p_cursor out sys_refcursor) as
begin
  open p_cursor for
    select min(t.doc_id) keep (dense_rank first order by t.activity_id) as doc_id,
      min(t.required_status) keep (dense_rank first order by t.activity_id) as required_status
    from your_table t
    where t.customer_type_id = p_customer_type_id
    and (t.activity_id = p_activity_id
     or (t.activity_id is null and t.category_id = p_category_id))
    group by t.customer_type_id, t.category_id;
end your_proc;
/
```

Then testing it:

```
var rc refcursor;

begin
  your_proc (p_customer_type_id => 1, p_category_id => 2,
    p_activity_id => 10, p_cursor => :rc);
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

print rc

    DOC_ID REQUIRED_STATUS
---------- ---------------
         1               4

begin
  your_proc (p_customer_type_id => 1, p_category_id => 2,
    p_activity_id => 42, p_cursor => :rc);
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

print rc

    DOC_ID REQUIRED_STATUS
---------- ---------------
         1               3
```

Comment: Im still geting all more then one row , the row with the actividyId and the second with the null.

Comment: mybe i cant filter the results some how? so i delete the row i dont need from the ous cursor?

Comment: @dor_dru - OK, updated to keep only one row in the result set.

Answer (score 0):

After understanding your problem below solution might help you.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_Search 
   @Activity_Id INT NULL,
   @CustTypeID INT ,
   @CategoryCode INT
AS 
BEGIN
 SELECT DOC_ID, CUSTOMER_TYPE_ID,CATEGORY_ID, REQUIERD_STATUS
 FROM myTable
 WHERE @Activity_ID IS NULL OR (Activity_ID = @Activity_ID)
 AND CATEGORY_ID = @CategoryCode

END
```

Comment: Just for your reference you can add If condition as well and write two separate queries.

Comment: The question is tagged Oracle, so this symtax isn't valid. I'm not sure the logic is right either, but might just be interpreting it differently.

Comment: Im still geting all more then one row , the row with the actividyId and the second with the null.